# how to draw multiple bar charts grouped by category with flot js

Tags: charts, flot, bar-chart

I'm using flot library to display a bar charts and I need to group by certain value in this way:

```
|
|          +----+        +----+    
|          |    |        |    |    
|          |    |        |    |    
|          |    |        |    |    
| +----+   |    |        |    |    
| |    |   |    |        |    |    
| |    |   |    |        |    |    
| |    |   |    |        |    |    
|-+----+---+----+--------+----+----
   val 1    val2          val3
    category #1        category #2
```

Thanks Sergey G. for the Ascii :)

I have the variables d1, d2, d3 to the values ​​of the bars 1, 2 and 3 respectively (sorted by category).
The question is:
How do I add the category below ticks?
Sorry for my bad "Google-Translator" English and thank you very much!

Code:

```
$.plot(
    $("#placeholder"),
    [

            {
        label: labelChart,
        data: d1,
        color: '#92d5ea',
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.5,
            align: "center",
            order:2
        },   

       multiplebars:true  
    },
    {
        label: labelChart,
        data: d2,
        color: '#92d5ea',
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.5,
            align: "center",
            order:3
        },   

       multiplebars:true  
    },
    {
        label: labelChart,
        data: d3,
        color: '#92d5ea',
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.5,
            align: "center",
            order:3
        },   

       multiplebars:true  
    }


    ],
    {
        xaxis: {
            ticks: ticksData
        }, 

        yaxis: { 
            min:0
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use the categories plugin, as demonstrated in [this example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html).

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote, as this doesn't answer the question.  In the example, one value is given per category. But the question is how to get multiple series graphed, presumably side by side, using categories.

Comment: @DerekHenderson You're correct; I clearly misread the question.  Removing my answer.

Comment: This worked for me: http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/tutorial-flot-how-to-create-bar-charts/